# Sending Mail while running the application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, smtp

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text.ToString());
            mailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text.ToString();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("my@gmail.com"));
            mailMessage.Body = txtSuggestion.Text.ToString();
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;


            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
            sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            sc.Port = 587;
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text.ToString(), txtPassword.Text.ToString());
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.Send(mailMessage);
            lblMessage.Text = "Message Sent Successfully";
            txtSubject.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtSuggestion.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

This is the code i am using to send email but whenever i am trying to run the application, i am getting error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tacuf.png)

if someone can help why i am getting the error, that would be great.

Comment: 1) Can you post the call stack?
2) With Gmail, this solved my issue - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: Your `Try Block` is getting Exception ,That's why its showing `Failure Sending Mail`. Remove `try Catch block` and post what original Exception is..without knowing type of exception We have to guess the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

When using SSL, try using port 465.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600

Answer (score 0):

You also have another issue with that code that's un-related to the one you're subscribing. When setting up contact us forms, using the person's email as the FROM field will cause DMARC to fail. You can read up about that [here](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

Also I don't understand why you are using the person's email address and password to connect to gmail with. You should use your own account if you're sending mail.